Variadic template class: Allow for float and int arguments cast to float?
I have the following class:
template <size_t N, float... Lam> requires (sizeof...(Lam) == N)
class Spectrum {
public:
    Spectrum() : wavelengths{ static_cast<float>(Lam)... }
    {
        values.fill(0.f);
    };

    template <IsNumeric T>
    Spectrum(T v) : wavelengths{ static_cast<float>(Lam)... }
    {
        values.fill(static_cast<float>(v));
    };

    template <IsNumeric... T> requires (sizeof...(T) == N)
    Spectrum(T... v) : wavelengths{ static_cast<float>(Lam)... }, values { static_cast<float>(v)... } 
    { };

... // Other methods/overloads that aren't relevant here

private:
    std::array<float, N> values;
    const std::array<float, N> wavelengths;
};

I can then call this using:
Spectrum<3, 450.f, 500.f, 600.f> color{ 1,2,3 };

And it behaves as expected (the wavelengths are populated with 450.f, 500.f, 600.f and the values are populated with 1.f, 2.f, 3.f.
I would like to be able to allow users to instead call:
Spectrum<3, 450, 500, 600> color{1,2,3};

in this case, 450 is an int, so I'd need it to be cast to a float, in a similar way to what I already do in the constructor templates.  I'm just not sure if a similar idea can be expressed in the class template itself.

Curious: Why are you repeating yourself?  (3 arguments coming, then 3 arguments)  You can literally do inline constexpr auto N = sizeof...(Lam); and get the constant if you need it.

I hadn't quite gotten to this part yet, but I wanted (at somepoint) to be allow for only N to be provided, and if no wavelengths are given, then a set of wavelengths would be precomputed by default.  Obviously I'm not doing any of that here yet, but that was my rationale for why the N is included separately.

Change float... Lam to auto... Lam?

Not really an issue but in the Spectrum(T... v) constructor you initialize your members in the reverse order.  This will cause warnings since class members get initialized in member declaration order.

template<auto...Lam>
using Spectrum_t = Spectrum<sizeof...(Lam), static_cast<float>(Lam)...>;

they don't even have to pass 3.  Not sure why you are passing it.
Also, storing Lam... in const wavelengths seems like a very strange choice.
static constexpr std::array<float, N> wavelengths() {
  return {{Lam...}};
}

or an inline constexpr static value.

What is strange about the storage of Lam into const wavelengths?  I'd appreciate the insight as to a better way.  All I really want is for the type itself to have a fixed set of wavelengths corresponding to the values it stores.  It wouldn't be obvious to me how to act directly on Lam... in later operations (if thats what you were implying)

@ChrisGnam You should basically never have const data members. It makes your type very hard to work with: clients can't swap, assign, use move semantics, standard algorithms... and it messes with your compiler's ability to construct optimal data layout. There are various ways to communicate immutability. If encapsulating within private section of your class is not enough, you can use std::reference_wrapper, or wrap that immutable data member in a class that has getters only. Or maybe just use smart pointers...

Thats a fair point.  So if I remove the const and simply have a private std::array<float, N> wavelengths, is there still a problem with that?  The only other thing I can think of would be to do something like:  static std::array<float, N> constexpr wavelengths{ Lam... };, I'd just be concerned with performance implications.  storing it directly in the object seemed reasonable to me, which is why I'm curious why it is a strange choice

@ChrisGnam I would make it static constexpr. That would certainly have good performance implications since it would be evaluated at compile time and would not affect your type's data layout. You can also do it with static constexpr function like Yakk has indicated. It would be the same.

Wouldn't a static member though have a performance penalty when accessed?  Or would it be able to be cached?  This is for a simulation where wavelengths may be accessed several billion times.  (Ultimately I think I'll just benchmark the various alternatives, I'm mostly asking for my own understanding).

Let the CPU cache handle that.  If its hot then the CPU will keep it loaded to be used.

@ChrisGnam There is a maxim called DRY.  Don't repeat yourself.  Your type already has the data. Why are you repeating this data in runtime storage?  The object type already stores it!  OTOH, a mere constexpr expression (static inline, or produced by a function) is a different "view" of the data so a different API could consume it.
